# Как преобразовывать с кодировки utf-8 в windows-1251 при вводе текста

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу преобразовывать с кодировки utf-8 в windows-1251 при вводе пользователя текст в поле

К примеру пользователь вводит:
Äèíóàáó

Хочу получить:
Aeioaao

Я использую костыль земной символов, но хотелось бы найти нормальный метод, в интернете ничего рабочего не удалось найти.

Что использую:

```js
    $(function(){
        $('#txt').on('keyup paste change', function(){ 
        var txt = $(this), val = txt.val();
        val = val.replace(/[\u00c4]/g, 'A').replace(/[\u00e8]/g, 'e').replace(/[\u00ed]/g, 'i').replace(/[\u00f3]/g, 'o').replace(/[\u00e0]/g, 'a').replace(/[\u00e1]/g, 'a').replace(/[\u00e7]/g, 'c');
        txt.val(val);
        })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Введите: Äèíóàáó</p>
<input type="text" id="txt">
```

Мне он помогает, так как восномном используют одни и тежи символы. Но если новый, надо его добавлять.

Comment: Что-то не очень понятен смысл задачи. Зачем преобразовывать один бессмысленный текст в другой бессмысленный текст? Ну и кодировки тут ни при чём — в показанном вами коде все манипуляции проводятся с чисто юникодными строками без всяких кодировок

Comment: @andreymal Мне именно нужен такой вариант как в примере, я связал это с кодировкой за Notepad++ так как при смене кодировки получается то что мне нужно.